# flex4 calling a function in addEventListener with dynamic suffix

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, dynamic, flex4, addeventlistener

I would like to call a function name from inside an addEventListener dynamically based on function parameter.

calling with `newMod("moduleA", "A");` however I am getting error `TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.`

Any suggestions on how I can call this function dynamically. I have seen some answers around using an `instance[function]()` but am not sure how that applies with the listener,

```
public function newMod(mdLd,evtTyp,param):void {
   info = ModuleManager.getModule(mdLd);
   var mevth:String =  ("modEventHandler"+(evtTyp));
   info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, function(e:ModuleEvent){
                this[mevth](e, param)});
   info.load(null, null, null, moduleFactory);
}
private function modEventHandlerA(e:ModuleEvent):void {
    vg1.addElement(info.factory.create() as IVisualElement);
    }
```

[EDIT]
looks like changing the call to `this[mevth]()` works, but I cant seem to pass additional params as needed i.e. `this[mevth](parm)`, any suggestions welcome.

I have also updated the listener to include a function call but still no joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create closure "this" doesn't point to real instance "this". You can write something like this

```
public function newMod(mdLd,evtTyp,param):void {
   info = ModuleManager.getModule(mdLd);
   var self:Object = this;
   var mevth:String =  ("modEventHandler"+(evtTyp));
   info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, function(e:ModuleEvent){
                self[mevth](e, param)});
   info.load(null, null, null, moduleFactory);
}

...
```

But I really don't recommend you write code like this.

Comment: thx for the response, can you suggest a better code format? I dont understand the term "closure" can you point to some info so I can understand this. thx Art

Comment: thx giving this the correct answer as it does what was asked and an up for pointing out that it could be better, thx Art

Answer (score 0):

To awnser your comment:

Function closure means that a function remembers the context in which it has been created. In your code the following line creates a closure:

```
info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, function(e:ModuleEvent){
            this[mevth](e, param)});
```

The event handler function is created in the context of the class that contains the method `public function newMod(mdLd,evtTyp,param):void`, so your handler has access to all members of the class. This includes variables declared in the surrounding method, the private variables/methods of the class and the protected variables/method in the whole inheritence chain of the class.

The problem with the `this` as *Ivan Dyachenko* wrote is that your handler function actually is an instance of the top-level class `Function`. So, if you try to call a method on `this` in a Function object it will be the same as calling a method in any other object - `this` refers to the object. In your case this will be the Function object. But your function doesn't have the method you want to call on it.

Additionally you will run into another problem with your code. Because you create the event handler inline - directly as argument of `addEventListener()` you will be unable to remove the event listener later. You should either use the `useWeakReference` parameter on `addEventListener()` as described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) or store the handler function in a variable to hold a reference on it to remove it later with `removeEventListener()`.

Comment: thx @freakazoid_em lots of detailed info there that will take some time to digest. I will try to work through them step by step and ask back if I hit a dead end.